# PasteSpecial SkipBlanks:=True fails with merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

```
Range1.Copy
Range2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, SkipBlanks:=True
```

If `Range1` and `Range2` have the same dimensions, this code executes without any trouble. The expectation is that the formulas in the range you copied will get inserted into the target range, but any blank cells in `Range1` will not have their formulas copied to `Range2`, instead, any current cell values will be left as they were.

I've discovered that this fails on merged cells. The image below demonstrates the equivalent action using the built in Paste Special UI, which fails in an identical fashion:

[image: skip blanks fails]

Can anyone think of an elegant workaround <s>that doesn't involve looping</s>?

Note that simply using a variant of `Range1.Formula = Range2.Formula` won't suffice since it will overwrite unwanted cells in `Range2` with blank (empty) values.

---

I've removed the no loops restriction because there doesn't seem to be a perfect solution otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the conclusion that this bug makes it impossible to do this without looping, I've come up with the following solution which I believe to be as elegant as possible with looping.

```
Dim col as Long
Dim cel as Range
For Each cel In src.Cells
    If cel.Formula <> vbNullString Then
        col = 1 + src.Column - cel.Column
        cel.Copy
        dst.Worksheet.Range(dst.Cells(1, col ), dst.Cells(dst.rows, col )).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    End If
Next cel
```

This lets you copy one row of data from a range `src` and paste formulas over multiple rows in a range `dst` with only one loop over the columns, while skipping blank. This method never overwrites any destination that should be left alone, so it works in all my use cases.

In a more complex situation where the source data had multiple rows as well as columns, this routine wouldn't work, and I imagine at least 2 levels of nested loops would be required.

Answer (score 1):

The following was tested and seems to work.

Assumptions:

- The first row cells in your post are `A1:E1`.
- The green highlighted row cells in your post are `A2:E2`.
- The range that needs to be partially overwritten is in row 4 (`A4:E4`).
- I have replicated the contents of cells A2:E2 all the way till cell `Q2`. So`F2:G2` are merged & blank, `H2` is blank, `I2` has "copy", and so on till `Q2` (which has "copy"). I just wanted to make sure that the method works with multiple merged areas.

  ```
  Sub skipBlanksWithMergedCells()
      Dim rngOrigin As Range, rngDestination As Range, rngSkip As Range
      Dim varTemp As Variant

      Set rngOrigin = Range("A2:Q2")
      Set rngDestination = Range("A4:Q4")
      ' Set pointer to range that needs to be skipped
      Set rngSkip = rngOrigin.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Offset(2, 0)
      ' Store its values into a variant
      varTemp = rngSkip.Value
      rngOrigin.Copy
      rngDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
      ' Revert original values from the variant
      rngSkip.Value = varTemp
  End Sub
  ```

This will work if `rngSkip` contains hard numbers or text, but it will fail if it contain formulas.. In that case, we need to set a pointer to the subrange of formulas and store them in another variant, using `varTempFormulas=range.formula` and then back again `range.formula=varTempFormulas`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can this be made to work with an arbitrary origin and destination? The example I gave was just an example, the offset between the two won't me a fixed `(2, 0)`. Other than that you seem to have addressed the main pain point.

Comment: Upon testing it seems this still fails if the original value is an array formula, or has mid-cell formatting, which cannot be stored or restored using range.formula property. I can't make assumptions about the contents of the destination cells. It seems that any solution that involves overwriting the original cell contents that should have been skipped, even just temporarily, might not work.

Merged cells are such a damned pain.

Comment: @Alain The offset part can be `abs(rngOrigin.row-rngDestination.row)` instead of `2`. For the other comment, I absolutely agree: a combination of merged cells + non-contiguous ranges is hard to tackle without any assumptions.. The format we can recover, if we store the `text` property in the variant, but not the array formulas. Also copying `rngSkip` to a temporary range, does not work: `rngSkip` is non-contiguous so we cannot paste the temporary range back to it. Not sure what else could help.. Maybe storing all properties in a custom object and back?

Answer (score 1):

Brute Force method:
I had this problem and used this solution.
Copy format for whole page to new temporary page.
Un-merge your page.  Do your copy with skip blanks.
Copy format from temporary page to old page.
Delete temporary page.